# How do I get the first array element which is an array itself?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an array of data which is :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [chat_categories] => one cat
        [display_name] => admin user
        [user_email] => testemail1@email.com
        [user_login] => user
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [chat_categories] => one cat
        [display_name] => Test User
        [user_email] => testemail@testsite.com
        [user_login] => testuser
    )

)
```

Now I want to get the first element from that array, check if the values display_name, user_email and user_login matches and update chat_categories column in a wordpress user table if matched successfully.

Comment: Well, you iterate over the elements of the outer array, check if the current element is of type array, compare the values you want to check and update the value you want to update.

Comment: You seem to almost be asking for two things here.  Can you clarify what "matches" means here in your PHP code?  Also, if you want help with a MySQL query, then you should show us the table structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen by matches i meant that, if the values in columns display_name, user_email and user_login matches with the data in the array, it should update the column chat_categories. My table has 4 columns which are already mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, in my case, this helped me,

```
   for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++){
    $data = $arr[$i];
    $chat_categories = $data[chat_categories];
    $display_name = $data[display_name];
    $user_email = $data[user_email];
    $user_login = $data[user_login];
    $success = $wpdb->query("UPDATE $userTableName SET chat_categories = '$chat_categories' WHERE user_email = '$user_email' AND user_login ='$user_login' ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `foreach loop` as:

```
$arr = array(
            "0" => array(
                   "chat_categories" => "one cat",
                   "display_name" => "admin user",
                   "user_email" => "testemail1@email.com",
                   "user_login" => "user"
             ),
           "1" => array(
                  "chat_categories" => "one cat",
                  "display_name" => "Test User",
                  "user_email" => "testemail@testsite.com",
                  "user_login" => "testuser"
            )
   );

foreach($arr as $innerArr){    
    $chat_categories = $innerArr["chat_categories"];
    $display_name = $innerArr["display_name"];
    $user_email = $innerArr["user_email"];
    $user_login = $innerArr["user_login"];
    $success = $wpdb->query("UPDATE $userTableName SET chat_categories = '".$chat_categories."' WHERE user_email = '".$user_email."' AND user_login ='".$user_login."'");
    }
```